# Submenu jquery, close the submenu when i click another submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, submenu

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu-menu-1 .menu-item a').click(function ()
     {
    var submenu = $(this).next();
    submenu.toggle();
    });
});
```

The problem is that these submenu open are overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $links = $('#menu-menu-1 .menu-item a').click(function () {
        var submenu = $(this).next();
        $subs.not(submenu).hide()
        submenu.toggle();
    });
    var $subs = $links.next();
});
```

Comment: And if i need the same submenu js but not by click, only by hover mouse? Can you help me please?